# Run Code According to Class type C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11, vector

I'm trying to run different codes according to what class the template type `T` is passed as.
I have 2 classes: `Media` and `Customer`.
I have a template `T` and a function `add(T type)`.

What I want it to be able to do is effectively recognize which Class is being passed as `T` and add that type to an array as shown below.

```
template <typename T>
void add(T type){

    if(type = Customer) { // This is pseudo code of what I want it to do

        allCustomers.push_back(type);
        cout << "Added Successfully";

    }

    else if (type = Media){
        allMedia.push_back(type);
        cout << "Added Successfully";
    }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to pass it:

```
add(Media("test","test"));
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to make this a template if you have two known types.

You simply can have:

```
void add( Customer c );
void add( Media m );
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the `if() else if()` statements in your code is that

```
allCustomers.push_back(type);
```

will give you a compiler error for type `Media` (supposed that `allCustomers` is a `std::vector<Customer>`) and vice versa for type `Customer` and

```
allMedia.push_back(type);
```

---

You can simply use function overloading to do this:

```
void add(const Customer& type){
    allCustomers.push_back(type);
    cout << "Added Successfully";

}

void add(const Media& type){
    allMedia.push_back(type);
    cout << "Added Successfully";
}
```

---

In case you have a common template implementation for other types than `Customer` and `Media` you can use template specialization as well:

```
template<typename T>
void add(const T& type){
    anyTypes.push_back(type);
    cout << "Added Successfully";

}

template<>
void add(const Customer& type){
    allCustomers.push_back(type);
    cout << "Added Successfully";

}

template<>
void add(const Media& type){
    allMedia.push_back(type);
    cout << "Added Successfully";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make two different definitions of `add` (this is called "specialization"):

```
template<typename T> void add(T);
template<> void add<Customer>(Customer c) {
    ...
}
template<> void add<Media>(Media m) {
    ...
}
...
```

The `template<>` syntax is necessary to declare that you're specializing a template function.

This is statically type-checked at compile time, so if you call `add(myPotato)` it will fail to compile.

Comment: Template specialization for only exactly known types is useless. As you see nothing depends on template parameters which shows you that template syntax is only waste in this case.